# Form isn't displayed in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django and I've been following a tutorial to help me create my project. My problem is that the form and its fields don't show up on my html page.

**line of code from my html file**

```
    <form action="admin/signup/" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in signupForm %}
                <p>
                    {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                    {{ field }}
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </p>
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </form>
```

**my signup form class**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
usertype = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
userID = forms.CharField(label="User ID")
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
        'password1', 'password2', 'userID', 'usertype')
```

**and my signup page view**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.usertype = form.clean_data.get('usertype')
            user.profile.userID = form.clean_data.get('userID')
            user.save()
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    context = {
        'signupForm' :form
    }
    return render(request, 'admin.html', context)
```

any possible solutions and suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "can't seem to display"?. It is displayed or not ? Do you have any error showing?

Comment: People in Python are really nazy about [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (at least for naming conventions: instances/functions/methods in snake_case and classes in CamelCase)

Comment: i don't get any errors. The form fields don't appear on the html page. Edited my question, thanks for the comment

Comment: Try to insert a `{% debug %}` tag and inspect the context (see the page source). Python is case sensitive, watch out for uppercase/lowercase mismatches between the template and view.

Answer (score 0):

May be indentation require in SignUpForm. Is it!!